# Can we not change the direction of vibrating electric field in electromagnetic wave in the following way?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization

Suppose we have a set of linear polarizers lined up with pass axis(P1, P2,...Pn),separated by very small distances and an unpolarized light is passed through the setup.
The polarizers are lined up in such a way that as we move along from P1 to Pn the pass axis is rotated by a very small angle.
Won't the emergent ray be polarized along the direction of pass axis of Pn?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But why all of the polarizers for that? Input: unpolarized light -> Output: polarized at Pn direction. You only need Pn.

I refer you to look into half-waveplates. These plates rotate the field without losses. Of course, you still need to polarize the field first (so, an unpolarized field through such a plate will still be unpolarized afterwards), but it does what you might have thought about.

Comment: THis is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Well, the question was "Is the output not polarized along Pn?" The answer is yes. But I will further talk about waveplates.

Comment: I'd like to add to my question that couldn't this also be the way to change the direction of polarization of the wave 'without much loss of energy'. Like, suppose the E field is vibrating along x as it enters P1(pass axis for P1 is suppose along x too) and as it reaches P2 since larger component is along P2 (less  δ theta value)so that passes through P2 and so on.This goes on unless the ray emerges through Pn and by then the electric field gets rotated by 90 degrees.

Comment: no, in that case you use a half-waveplate. No losses.